# java HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod() doesn't work

Tags: java, httprequest

i want to change the request methodo from GET to POST. This is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;  

     URL url = new URL("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

     connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     connection.setUseCaches (false);
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

But as u see in this image while debugging the methodo of the request doesn't change:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

That's just an [implementation detail](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java#HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29). The `HttpsURLConnectionImpl` object has a reference to a delegate, and sets that delegate's request method. If you expand the `delegate` field and check its `method` field, you'll see `POST`.

If you follow through with the code, you'll also see it attempts to send a POST request.

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:-Use below code:-

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String urlParameters = "";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();


    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

Solution 2:- Use Spring / Netty rest template

```
public class HttpRequestProcessor {

@Autowired
private AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;

private static final Logger logger_c = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(HttpRequestProcessor.class);

public enum HttpMethod {
    HTTP_GET, HTTP_POST, HTTP_DELETE
}

public static final int HTTP_GET = 1;
public static final int HTTP_POST = 2;
public static final int HTTP_DELETE = 3;

// private static AsyncHttpClient client;


  public HttpRequestProcessor() {

  LOGGER.info("HttpRequestProcessor created");


  Create Nett Http provider configuration for asynchronous connect
  operation

  NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig nettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig = new
  NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig(); nettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig.addProperty(
  NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig.EXECUTE_ASYNC_CONNECT, true);
  nettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig.addProperty(
  NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig.DISABLE_NESTED_REQUEST, false);

  AsyncHttpClientConfig config = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
  .setAllowPoolingConnection(true) .setAllowSslConnectionPool(true)
  .setMaximumConnectionsPerHost(500) .setMaximumConnectionsTotal(800)
  .setIdleConnectionTimeoutInMs(60000)
  .setConnectionTimeoutInMs(5000).setRequestTimeoutInMs(25000)
  .setAsyncHttpClientProviderConfig(nettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig) .build();

  client = new AsyncHttpClient(new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(config), config);
  }


private String getRequestType(HttpMethod method) {
    switch (method) {
    case HTTP_DELETE:
        return "DELETE";
    case HTTP_GET:
        return "GET";
    case HTTP_POST:
        return "POST";
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

private RequestBuilder createRequestBuilder(HttpMethod method, String url,
        Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> queryParameters) {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
            getRequestType(method));
    requestBuilder.setUrl(url);
    if (headers != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
        }
    }
    if (queryParameters != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> requestParameter : queryParameters
                .entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.addQueryParameter(requestParameter.getKey(),
                    requestParameter.getValue());
        }
    }
    return requestBuilder;
}

public Future<?> submitRequest(HttpMethod method, String url,
        Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> queryParameters,
        Map<String, String> postParameters, String bodyData,
        AsyncHandler<?> asyncHandler) throws IOException {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = createRequestBuilder(
            HttpMethod.HTTP_POST, url, headers, queryParameters);
    if (postParameters != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> posParameter : postParameters
                .entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.addParameter(posParameter.getKey(),
                    posParameter.getValue());
        }
    }
    if (bodyData != null)
        requestBuilder.setBody(bodyData);
    return submitRequest(requestBuilder.build(), asyncHandler);
}

public Future<?> submitPostRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
        Map<String, String> queryParameters,
        Map<String, String> postParameters, AsyncHandler<?> asyncHandler)
        throws IOException {
    return submitRequest(HttpMethod.HTTP_POST, url, headers,
            queryParameters, postParameters, null, asyncHandler);
}

public Future<?> submitPostRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
        Map<String, String> queryParameters, String bodyData,
        AsyncHandler<?> asyncHandler) throws IOException {
    return submitRequest(HttpMethod.HTTP_POST, url, headers,
            queryParameters, null, bodyData, asyncHandler);
}

public Future<?> submitGetRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
        Map<String, String> queryParameters, AsyncHandler<?> asyncHandler)
        throws IOException {
    return submitRequest(
            createRequestBuilder(HttpMethod.HTTP_GET, url, headers,
                    queryParameters).build(), asyncHandler);
}

public Future<?> submitRequest(Request request, AsyncHandler<?> asyncHandler)
        throws IOException {
    return asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request, asyncHandler);
}

/
  public Future<Response> submitGetRequests(String url, String bodyParam,
  AsyncCompletionHandlerBase asyncHandler) throws IOException {

  RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder("GET").setUrl(url); //
  requestBuilder.setBody(bodyParam); Future<Response> responseFuture =
  asyncHttpClient.executeRequest( requestBuilder.build(), new
  AsyncCompletionHandlerBase());

  return responseFuture; }
 /

public Future<?> submitPostRequest(String url,
        Map<String, String> requestHeaders, String body,
        AsyncCompletionHandlerBase asyncHandler) throws IOException {
    return submitRequest(
            createRequestBuilder(HttpMethod.HTTP_POST, requestHeaders, url,
                    body).build(), asyncHandler);
}

private RequestBuilder createRequestBuilder(HttpMethod method,
        Map<String, String> requestHeaders, String url, String body) {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
            getRequestType(method));
    requestBuilder.setUrl(url);
    requestBuilder.setBody(body);

    requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    if (requestHeaders != null)
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : requestHeaders.entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    logger_c.info("Request is :" + requestBuilder.toString());
    return requestBuilder;
}
```

}