# HttpUrlConnection ignores the entered values

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make a **HttpUrlConnection POST** to the PayPal sandbox token to get an access token, but when I run my app it ignores the entered values (method, `doOutput`...).
I tried **`HttpsUrlConnection`** too.
***Where is the problem?***

This method is called from the **`AsyncTask`** class, inside the **`doInBackground()`** method.

```
private String makeHttpAuth(URL authURL) throws IOException, JSONException {
// authUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
// BASICINPUT = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(AUTHINPUT.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

String authJsonResponse = "";
String grant = authBody().toString();

    if (authURL == null) {
        return authJsonResponse;
    }
    HttpURLConnection authentication = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {

        authentication = (HttpURLConnection) authURL.openConnection();
        authentication.setRequestMethod("POST");
        authentication.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        authentication.setRequestProperty(AUTHORIZE, BASICINPUT);
        authentication.setDoInput(true);
        authentication.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(authentication.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(grant);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        authentication.connect();

        if (authentication.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = authentication.getInputStream();
            authJsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + authentication.getResponseCode());
        }

    } finally {
        if (authentication != null) {
            authentication.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return authJsonResponse;
```

**Expected:**

...

- method: "**POST**"
- doOutput: **true**
- responseCode: **200**

...

**Actual:**

...

- method: "**GET**"
- doOutput: **false**
- responseCode: **-1**

...

Comment: How are you printing that result? I tried the same code with a https://httpbin.org/post url and it seems to work just fine

Comment: Next method uses returned value in (actual null) (toast). I run it also with debugger

Comment: App and debugger - Android Studio

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114781/1019366

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!